# How to use OpenSSL to generate SHARSA1 base64 signature

Tags: bash, openssl, rsa, sha1

I have generated a public/private keypair with OpenSSL. I want to use the private key now to sign my message using OpenSSL, and I was thinking to stay in a bash environment. I am required to use SHA-RSA1.

So far, I was suggested the following code but I am not happy with it:

```
 openssl.exe dgst -sha1 -sign C:\...\path\to\key\privatekey.pem -binary C:\...\path\to\message\message.txt
```

I don't want to have my message be stored in a file (message.txt) to generate a signature and in any case, I would need to use `openssl base64` afterwards to get the base64 representation.

Is there a more proper way to achieve what I want (and a one liner would be great)?

Comment: Pass the message from sdtin `echo "$msg" | openssl dgst ... -binary | openssl enc base64`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, thank you very much! That put me on the right track and eventually ended up with `echo "$msg" | openssl dgst ... -binary | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n'` to get what I want.

Comment: cool! Added as an answer in case you want to accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use openssl itself to encode base64

`echo "$msg" | openssl dgst ... -binary | openssl enc -base64`